# Ruby on Rails demo app syntax error using scaffold

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, railstutorial.org

I am very new to Ruby on Rails and I was following the Railstutorial to make a demo app using Scaffold.

First when I added the User model using scaffold, it worked fine. Then, when I added the micropost model, I kept getting the following error:

```
/demo_app/app/models/micropost.rb:4: syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting keyword_end
  belongs_to: user
```

I noticed that the code generated by scaffold did not generate the same code as shown in the tutorial. Here is the User and Microposts model :

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :email, :name
  has_many :microposts
end

class Micropost < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :content, :user_id

  belongs_to: user

  validates :content, :length => { :maximum => 140 }
end
```

The `attr_accessible` line is not there in the tutorial.  what is this exactly and is this the problem? 
I have run the Rake program and everything else that was mentioned.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be `belongs_to :user`. You better use some texteditor with highlight for rails

Answer (score 1):

The error message says anything you need to know.

- look into line 4 of micropost.rb
- search for a ':'

it should be `belongs_to :user` instead of `belongs_to: user`